# How to set preload scope for Rails Associations::Preloader?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, preloader

I need to preload associations of the model with complex conditions. NO, `includes` doesn't work for me. It generate wrong SQL for my task.

I take a look to the `ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader` and find that he take an `preload_scope` argument:

http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Associations/Preloader/preload

```
 def preload(records, associations, preload_scope = nil)
  # ...
 end
```

But I can't find any example using it. What is `preload_scope` in this case? And how I can use it for filtering associations?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveRecord doesn't expose this through `#preloads` on relation:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0aefa97689d001ca9a98db76bbad1bbbb0e51c9c/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L663 – as you can see only records and associations parameters are passed.

You can reach into ActiveRecord internals and call Preloader directly:

```
rows = Projects.all.to_a
ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new.preload(rows, :current_task, Struct.new(:values, :bind_values).new({where: "active"}, []))
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, it works! But why it creates so many queries?

  `User Load (12.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (created_at > '2015-01-01') AND "users"."cat" IN (52, 50, 51, 53)
  User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (created_at > '2015-01-01')
  User Load (5.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"`

Comment: `users = Car.find(1).users

     rows = users.to_a
     ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new.preload(rows, :activities, Struct.new(:values, :bind_values).new({where: "created_at > '2015-01-01'"}, []))`

Comment: The excessive number of queries was also highlighted [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20704) (but not investigated by Rails team since they consider Preloader private stuff)

Comment: How could you use the `preload_scope` to return a limit? For example return only 5 elements?