# includes with where clause in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to preload associations but if no associations exist I would like to return the main relation.

To understand my issue here is a reproducible script :

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
gem 'rails'
require 'active_record'

puts "Active Record #{ActiveRecord::VERSION::STRING}"

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: 'sqlite3',
  database: ':memory:'
)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :organisations, force: true do |t|
    t.string 'name', limit: 255, null: false
    t.datetime 'created_at'
    t.datetime 'updated_at'
  end

  create_table :groups, force: true do |t|
    t.string 'name', limit: 255, null: false
    t.integer 'shop_id', null: false
    t.datetime 'created_at'
    t.datetime 'updated_at'
  end

  create_table :groups_organisations, force: true do |t|
    t.integer  'organisation_id', null: false
    t.integer  'group_id', null: false
    t.datetime 'created_at'
    t.datetime 'updated_at'
  end
end

class Organisation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups_organisations
  has_many :groups, through: :groups_organisations
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups_organisations
  has_many :organisation, through: :groups_organisations
end

class GroupsOrganisation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :organisation
end

organisation_without_groups = Organisation.create!(name: 'my organisation without groups')
group_1 = Group.create!(name: 'group_1', shop_id: 1)
group_2 = Group.create!(name: 'group_2', shop_id: 2)
organisation_with_groups = Organisation.create!(name: 'my organisation with groups', groups: [group_1, group_2])
```

When I don't have records to include

```
p Organisation.where(name: 'my organisation without groups').includes(:groups).where(groups: { shop_id: 1 })
# <ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

When I have records to include

```
p Organisation.where(name: 'my organisation with groups').includes(:groups).where(groups: { shop_id: 1 })
# <ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Organisation id: 2, name: "my organisation with groups", created_at: "2017-07-21 09:45:07", updated_at: "2017-07-21 09:45:07">]>
```

The SQL I get is

```
puts Organisation.where(name: 'my organisation witReproduce the actual bug!hout groups').includes(:groups).where(groups: { shop_id: 1 }).to_sql
```

Where clause is performed on all the query not on the LEFT OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT "organisations"."id" AS t0_r0,
       "organisations"."name" AS t0_r1,
       "organisations"."created_at" AS t0_r2,
       "organisations"."updated_at" AS t0_r3,
       "groups"."id" AS t1_r0,
       "groups"."name" AS t1_r1,
       "groups"."shop_id" AS t1_r2,
       "groups"."created_at" AS t1_r3,
       "groups"."updated_at" AS t1_r4
FROM "organisations"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "groups_organisations" 
             ON "groups_organisations"."organisation_id" = "organisations"."id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "groups" 
             ON "groups"."id" = "groups_organisations"."group_id"
WHERE "organisations"."name" = 'my organisation without groups'
  AND "groups"."shop_id" = 1
```

What I would like is

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN "groups" 
             ON "groups"."id" = "groups_organisations"."group_id"
            AND groups.store_id = 20441
WHERE "organisations"."name" = 'my organisation without groups'
```

Is it possible to preload using LEFT OUTER JOIN with conditionals?

Comment: use `ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695265/how-to-set-preload-scope-for-rails-associationspreloader

Comment: Thanks. As mention in https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20704 *The Active Record Preloader API is private and not intended for public use.* :/

Comment: Yes, but it works and your main query still has ability to use `.select()`. When accepted answer are using trick and has no one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to select where groups.shop_id is 1 or where there is no groups.shop_id

You can do that with a test for `nil`

```
Organisation.where(name: 'my organisation without groups').includes(:groups).where(groups: { shop_id: [nil, 1] })
```

Comment: I already thought about this solution but is it the result I want? I don't know

Answer (score 3):

For a general approach, [this](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes) documentation on `.includes()` is very useful.

Especially the bit on conditions:

> If you want to add string conditions to your included models, you'll have to explicitly reference them. For example:
>
> ```rb
> User.includes(:posts).where('posts.name = ?', 'abcd')
> ```
>
> Will throw an error, but **this will work**:
>
> ```rb
> User.includes(:posts).where('posts.name = ?', 'abcd').references(:posts)
> ```
>
> Note that includes works with association names while references needs the actual table name.
>
> If you pass the conditions via hash, you don't need to call references explicitly, as where references the tables for you. For example, **this will work**:
>
> ```rb
> User.includes(:posts).where(posts: { name: 'abcd' })
> ```

---

---

To take it one association further, if you had

```
thing.other_things.includes(:even_more_things)
.where(other_things: {col1: 'value'})
```

and you wanted to filter on `even_more_things`, you could use:

```
thing.other_things.joins(:even_more_things)
.where(even_more_things: { attribute: value })
```