# Rails active record includes condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this use case.

```
Project:
  has_many :assignments

Assignment:
  has_many :assignments_users, class_name: "AssignmentsUsers"
  has_many :assignees, through: :assignments_users, source: :user
```

assignments_users: 
is simply user_id and assignment_id.

I'd like to be able to do something like this.

```
projects = Project.includes(:assignments, {assignments: :assginments_users}).where("assignments.assignments_users.user_id = 6")
```

Where if I was to access assignments from a given project in the list, I would only see assignments where one of the users assigned is a user with id 6.

is this even do able?

I was thinking maybe I make an extra `has_many my_assignments, (user_id) -> { where(match_something_to_my_user_id) }`

is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is pretty close to something that should work:

```
projects = Project.
  includes(assignments: :assignments_users).
  where(assignments_users: { user_id: 6 })
```

Alternatively, it might be neater to approach from the other side:

```
Assignment:
  belongs_to :project

User:
  has_many :assignments_users, class_name: "AssignmentsUsers"
  has_many :assignments, through: :assignments_users
  has_many :active_projects, through: :assignments, source: :project

my_user.active_projects
```

Comment: I'm gonna mark this as the answer but its still not 100% what I'm looking for. 
Maybe you can help me with the rest. 

The problem I have with this is that it limits the projects. Where I only wanted to limit the associations of assignments. 

IE: Say I have 10 projects. I want to return all 10 projects but if I say project.assignment I'd only see assignments where that condition is true. 

What I'm trying to prevent is an N+1 but I may not have a choice in the matter

Comment: Ah, sorry, there aren't great options there. `includes` does use a left join, so `where("user_id = 6 OR user_id IS NULL")` could kinda do something... otherwise, I believe there are ways you can hack it using private API -- see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29963082/476979